# Magazine story about traffic cops in the future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This story was about traffic cops in the future that patrolled major highways in a RV-like vehicle that had food preparation facilities, sleeping berths for the off-duty officers and if I remember correctly an execution chamber for second offenders.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like this is a novella (then novel) called *[Code Three](http://manybooks.net/titles/raphaelr1911119111.html)*.  The author was Rick Raphael.

> Get in Beulah, the massive 60 ft long freeway cruiser and patrol the law enforcement lane of tomorrows freeways with 2 male troopers and a female EMT in this Heinleinesque novella.
>
> The freeways are a mile wide with lanes crossing over from 100mph to 400mph. The cruiser patrols the middle lane and in addition to being jet powered, had a an emergency surgery, food and sleeping quarters for the crew, a crane, and much more stuff including monitoring gear and a pair of .25 cal machine guns mounted up front. Hand out citations, clear wrecks, rescue people, fight the bad guys deliver a baby and chuckle at the repressed sexual tension between the crewmembers.

Comment: The downloadable ebook at the link I posted has the February 63 Analog with the story Code Three in it. It makes up approximately the first 1/3 of the novel, published in 1967.

http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?264971